# Need to order MySQL table and return specific subset

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I asked a question close to this yesterday but need to take it a step further.  I know that on any table you can specify what row to start on and how many rows to return using the

```
SELECT ... LIMIT <start-row>, <length>
```

command.

I also know that you can order tables on column heading using the

```
ORDER BY <column-name>
```

command.

What I want to know is, is there anyway to combine these so that MySQL will order a table alphabetically, and then only return a specific subset from the newly ordered table?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

write them both:

```
select foo
from bar
order by baz
limit 0,10;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just add the 'Order By' after your WHEREs and GROUPs and before your LIMITs.

Answer (score 1):

yes

```
SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY name LIMIT 0, 300
```